# Is it possible to merge the cells in a UITableView so that i can add some image at the right side?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

[image]

As seen in the image of my design that i have attached, i want to merge(don't know wether thats the correct word) the first three cells so that i can display an image at the right side in the table itself. Is it possible?

Comment: You could make your first three cells into one large cell. Then in that large cel put another tableview (with 3 cells) and one imageview next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can add your imageView as subview of tableView, so your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will working as usual

[image]

Comment: sure, it's pretty simple: `_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 200, 400)];
        _tableView.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
        
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultavatar.jpg"];
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(125, 0, 75, 132);
        [_tableView addSubview:_imageView];`

Answer (score 3):

**No** it's not possible. Instead, you can create first three as one cell(type1), other cells are other type(type2).

**Update:** [see this tutorial](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-custom-cell-and-delegates/) for how to create custom cell.

Comment: Do you have any idea about customCell ?

Comment: And how should he put one image view above three cells?

Comment: No You didn't understand that. You have created one cell with one image and three label which is one cell type and remaining are other cell type.

Comment: @iMani: yes, i know custom cell and also i thought of creating a cell in which there is an image but having three labels is fine in a cell but can those sections be made which looks like a table? I think its not possible,thats why thought of posting the question here.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a UIView with fixed dimensions(say, 200x200) having 3 textfields (number, name & uom) to left and add UIImageView to right. Create IBOutlet of this view and name it. Add this view to the header of your UITableview.

```
self._table.tableHeaderView = yourview;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [**UICollectionView**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) instead and apply a [**custom layout**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html) to achieve this.

> Collection views provide the same general function as table views
>   except that a collection view is able to support more than just
>   single-column layouts. Collection views support customizable layouts
>   that can be used to implement multi-column grids, tiled layouts,
>   circular layouts, and many more. You can even change the layout of a
>   collection view dynamically if you want.

There are many tutorials on the Internet:

http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Another option is to use **UITableView** and a custom **UITableViewCell**.

Example:
http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/customizing.html

Answer (score 1):

add it in the first cell.The size of you imageview shoud be greater than the cell height.Make sure cell.cliptobounds is set false.Make sure you set the zpositon of imageview to 1 by imageView.layer.zPosiziton = 1.