# Custom UITableView - creating merged/combined rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my UITableView, I have rows each containing information from a Story object, or rows that contain information from multiple Story objects. For the sake of consistency, in my data source I use an Epic class that contains >1 Story; single-Story rows get info from an Epic object that only holds one Story.

In the design, a row containing a multiple-Story Epic essentially looks the same as series of single-Story rows, except with UI elements crossing between them. But other that, there's not much of a difference between the two types of rows.

So I have a custom UITableViewCell subclass for drawing single-Story rows. My question is it possible to create Epic rows by first drawing each Story cell in a loop, then adding them as subviews of an Epic row, and then displaying it in cellForRowAtIndexPath: ? Is it possible to add UITableViewCell objects as subviews of another UITableViewCell? If not, what's the right approach for this?

You can think of multi-Story/Epic rows as "merged" cells, similar in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909102/is-it-possible-to-merge-the-cells-in-a-uitableview-so-that-i-can-add-some-image). However, I would like to use the same UITableViewCell subclass for both single-Story and Epic rows, since Epics are composed of multiple stories.

Is it possible to use two separate cell identifiers with the same UITableViewCell subclass?

Alternatively, since Epic's have a good amount of dynamic content inside, and are much viewer in the table compared to single-Story instances, I might not want to reuse them at all. Is it possible to populate a UITableView with cells that are generated each time on scrolling instead of being dequeued?