# Custom UITableView- Drawing multiple cells for each row for index path

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

Similar question to [Custom UITableView - creating merged/combined rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624000/custom-uitableview-creating-merged-combined-rows)

Basically, I'd like to create a table view where there are both single cells (from a UITableViewCell subclass), and multiple-cell rows that are those single cell rows repeated, plus some UI connecting them.

The array I'm sending to tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: holds an object that can either represent a single row, or an array of multiple rows. So, is it possible to use tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to generate and insert multiple UITableViewCell objects for a single IndexPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Table views are not designed to work this way. You could probably craft a custom cell that had multiple views inside it representing your sub-cells, but it would be difficult.

It sounds to me like what you want is a sectioned table view. Does that not meet your needs?

If a sectioned table view won't do what you want you might want to look at `UICollectionView`. They are much more flexible.

Comment: Is it possible to get a UICollectionView to draw like a UITableView, i.e. have the cells draw across the width of a screen and be arrayed one after another vertically, instead of being squares that are lined up horizontally?

I already have other sections in the table view, so unfortunately that doesn't help, unless there was some way to create sub-sections.

Comment: You can set up collection views in just about any layout you want, although sections and sub-sections might be a challenge.